# Accidents with `echo >` and `echo >>`

Tags: bash, append, overwrite, io-redirection

Today I learned the distinction between `echo >` and `echo >>` when I overwrote my log file.  I don't trust myself and know I'll make this mistake again unless I make this idiot proof.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Practice, more practice, and yet more practice — and don't write I/O redirections without thinking what you mean.  Beware of using `set -o noclobber` and then using `>!` extravagantly; that defeats the objective.

Comment: `noclobber` is a way, but it might cause bigger accidents in the future: When you trust the safety belt in your own environment and want to help a colleague (or on another system or as root), you start overwriting files again.

Answer (score 4):

Open your `~/.bashrc` file and put `set -o noclobber` at the end.

Now whenever `echo >` is called on an existing file, the file will not be overwritten and an error will appear saying: `-bash: FILENAME: cannot overwrite existing file`.

Remember to do `source ~/.bashrc` for these changes to take effect!

Comment: You might note that if you have `noclobber` set, doing "`echo 123 > xyz; echo 456 > xyz`" will generate an error on the second, as intended.  However, sometimes you need to override it.  Obviously, you can use `unset noclobber; echo 456 > xyz; set -o noclobber`, but you can also use `echo 456 >! xyz`.  Be cautious though — if you find yourself routinely writing `>!`, then the `noclobber` really isn't helping and you need to think accurately when working.